# Why does TypeScript not allow passing an array with the spread operator as function parameters?

Tags: typescript

This is how the JavaScript spread operator allows passing an array as function arguments:

```
function f(a, b) { console.log(a, b) }
let arr = [1, 2]
f(...arr) // all fine!
```

TypeScript 5.3.2 does not accept this, however:

```
function f(a, b) { console.log(a, b) }
let arr = [1, 2]
f(...arr) // error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.(2556)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrgBQEMA0wBGBKYAb2BhQGckAbAUwDoqkBzTHA4AXwChRha5gGAE5DgAXmABtAIw4ATAF0eoZSDBo6m4UMJA)

To me this is a bug, because valid JavaScript should always be valid TypeScript.

How can I circumvent this error, why does it occur?

Found a long discussion in the TypeScript repo: [`microsoft/TypeScript#49700`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49700).

Comment: _"valid JavaScript should always be valid TypeScript"_ - absolutely not, the whole point of TS is to disallow some JS. The message **tells you** why it's not allowed: either you need a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (so it can match the number, types and positions to the function arguments) or a rest argument (so the number doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the default inferred type for `arr` is `number[]`, so a normal array with unspecified length.

If you explicitly specify `arr` to be a tuple (compatible with the function signature), e.g. `[number, number]`, it works correctly. E.g.:

```
function f(a: unknown, b: unknown) { console.log(a, b) }
let arr: [unknown, unknown] = [1, 2]
f(...arr)
```

Comment: right, the unspecified length is the complaint. switching between languages i forgot that a tuple in ts is an array of some length.

Comment: Instead of explicitly specifying a type you can also use the [const-assertion with the assigned value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#readonly-and-const) so its type is automatically inferred as a tuple: `let arr = [1, 2] as const`